# how to use animate function with before function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to use both animate and before function.
I have the list item and I want to animate while swapping the item.

Swapping works fine but I want to add animate 'slow'.
I want to swap the list with transformation.

Is it possible to use animate 'slow' function while swapping?
I want to move to left with animation.
If I click the next button images swapped without animation.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    $(secondLi).before(fourthLi); //animate while swapping
    //$(secondLi).animate(before(fourthLi),slow);  I have tried as
  });

 });
$('.flex-prev').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    $(secondLi).after(fourthLi);
  });

 });

});
```

```css
.content__teaser {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 110px;
}
.contentContainer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul .thumbnailIcon {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 31%;
  height: 100%;
}
.thumbnailIcon li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 16px;
  height: 110px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
.thumbnailIcon .img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff !important;
}
.thumbnailIcon .img-circle {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff !important;
}
.content__teaser img {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li>1<img class="videoThumbnail img-circle" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" draggable="false" style="width: 100px;"></li>
  <li >2<img class="videoThumbnail img-circle" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" draggable="false" style="width: 100px;"></li>
  <li >3 <img class="videoThumbnail img-circle" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" draggable="false" style="width: 100px;"></li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>

<a  class="flex-prev">prev<a>
<a  class="flex-next">next<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you looking for and If I understand correctly you looking for effect of moving element.

**JsFiddler link** https://jsfiddle.net/rj1405/tcpk6xde/2/

I just extended your code and used the **.fadeIn** and **.fadeOut** animation methods.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.flex-next').click(function(){
     $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
     var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
     var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
     $(fourthLi).fadeToggle( "slow", function() {
       $(secondLi).before(fourthLi).fadeIn("slow");
     });
     $(fourthLi).fadeIn("slow");
   });
});
```

You can check the output here

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    $(fourthLi).fadeToggle( "slow", function() {
     $(secondLi).before(fourthLi).fadeIn("slow");
   });
    $(fourthLi).fadeIn("slow");
 });
});
$('.flex-prev').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    $(secondLi).after(fourthLi);
  });

 });

});
```

```css
.content__teaser {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 110px;
}
.contentContainer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul .thumbnailIcon {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 31%;
  height: 100%;
}
.thumbnailIcon li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 16px;
  height: 110px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
.thumbnailIcon .img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff !important;
}
.thumbnailIcon .img-circle {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff !important;
}
.content__teaser img {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li>1<img class="videoThumbnail img-circle" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" draggable="false" style="width: 100px;"></li>
  <li >2<img class="videoThumbnail img-circle" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" draggable="false" style="width: 100px;"></li>
  <li >3 <img class="videoThumbnail img-circle" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" draggable="false" style="width: 100px;"></li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>

<a  class="flex-prev">prev<a>
<a  class="flex-next">next<a>
```